# Moving a compact submanifold off of another submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, compact-manifolds

This is an intuitive idea that I see referenced a lot. Consider the following situation. Let $M$ and $N$ be submanifolds, $M$ compact, in some larger manifold $X$. Suppose also that $\dim(M)+\dim(N)<\dim(X)$. Since there are enough dimensions to "move around," we can pull $M$ off of $N$ with a very small perturbation.

Is there a rigourous proof of this concept? Let me try to state my question more formally.

> With $M$ and $N$ as above, does there always exist a deformation $\iota_t(M)$ of $M$ such that $\iota_1(M)\cap N=\emptyset$, but $|m-\iota_1(m)|\leq\epsilon$ for all $m\in M$ where $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary.

(Please let me know if my question doesn't make sense as posed. Thanks.)

Comment: I think it makes sense, but I am not sure one dimension is enough (although this is really just me saying stuff, I don't claim to have enough intuition to explain what I feell...)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this follows from the transversality theorem, as long as you are working with smooth manifolds. This is exercise 5 of chapter 2, section 3 of Guillemin and Pollack. The basic idea is that we can do a small homotopy to make any two submanifolds of an ambient manifold intersect transversely, but if $\dim X+ \dim Y < \dim Z$, the only way for them to intersect transversely is for them to not intersect at all.

Comment: I didn't know about transversality, this is an interesting property! +1! I'll look it up if I have time.